# Зачем нужен знак "?" в адресной строке

Tags: http

Мне нужно сделать страницы пользователей, но я не знаю как, не создавать же отдельный html-файл для каждого пользователя. Много раз замечал в адресной строке знак "?" (Например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/ вот он>?<вот он newreg=7ef80dea9c5c4a94ba59f3abc21837ac) , пронаблюдав, в каких случаях его используют пришел к выводу, что это то, что мне нужно, однако я все ещё не знаю, что это такое и как этим пользоваться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это такое и, если не трудно, ссылку на сайт, где можно ознакомиться с его использованием

Comment: Вам нужно изучить какой-нибудь язык программирования и какой-нибудь веб-фреймворк для него, с "?" это связано очень слабо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать одну страницу, которая будет показывать данные пользователя по его айди. Айди будет передаваться в строке. После знака "?" идут GET-параметры запроса, где вы можете получить id пользователя. К примеру http://test.com/user.php?id=52

Для обработки этих параметров вам нужны серверные технологии (я выбрал php), теперь после получения Id вы можете показать данные о пользователе так:
"Покажи мне имя пользователя, у которого Id=52", данные о пользователях можно хранить в базе данных.

И так, подводим этоги, для отображения пользователя нужна одна страница, а знак "?" отделяет домен сайта от GET-параметров запроса.

Comment: *"Для обработки этих параметров вам нужны серверные технологии"* – у вас явно сильно устаревшая или неполная информация.

Comment: В любом случае на HTML вряд ли получится сделать страницу аккаунта.

Answer (score 0):

Знак вопроса отделяет адрес от передаваемых данных.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_URL